# Jest time out when I use mongoose model inside the test

Tags: node.js, testing, mongoose, jestjs

I got this error when I  run tests

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 10000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 10000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

my test

```
it('should return products', async ()  => {
    const y =  Product.find({});
    console.log("Producttttts", y);
});
```

jest config

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    verbose: true
};
```

I also tried to increase the timeout and the same error appears

Comment: Is this your only test? Are you sure it is the one that is failing? Also, if the method `Product.find` is asynchronous, you should put an `await` just before you call it for the test to wait until the promise is resolved.

Comment: when I use await or when I use then or cacth if fails .. I will compelete the test for sure and add assertions but I it's not working as it is now :(

Comment: First of all, unit testing or integration testing?

Comment: integration test